# proxy pass http 2 with nginx

Tags: nginx, proxypass, http2

I tried to proxy pass all inbound traffic with nginx. I use [this repo](https://github.com/sajad-sadra/proxy-pass-http-and-https) with this`nginx.conf` and works properly.

```
http{
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        resolver ${RESOLVER} ipv6=off;
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://$host$request_uri;    
        }

    }
}

stream {
    server {    
        resolver ${RESOLVER} ipv6=off;
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $ssl_preread_server_name:443;
    }
}
```

But problem is that doesn't support **HTTP/2** :(

Do you have any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **`http2`** to the `listen` directive like this:

```
stream {
    server {
        resolver ${RESOLVER} ipv6=off;
        listen 443 http2;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $ssl_preread_server_name:443;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx proxy module does not support HTTP/2 by far.

Comment: It can't use http2 to talk with the backend. But its own listener *can* use http2.